# How to deal with a large amount of np.inf entries in data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am working on a project where I am creating inputs for a neural net based on KNN search of a given point and time, and then aggregating the results:

```
lat              -24.300000
long              16.600000
time            1119.925430
ave_d              1.796321
ave_dt            10.425430
last_event         8.925430
violence_rem       0.000000
battles            0.000000
violence_civ       0.000000
protests           2.000000
stategic           0.000000
riots              0.000000
fatalites          0.000000
future             1.000000
```

The search results are restricted to a time and space radius, so sometimes the results come back as:

```
lat              -36.300000
long             -54.700000
time            1148.393299
ave_d                   inf
ave_dt                  inf
last_event              inf
violence_rem       0.000000
battles            0.000000
violence_civ       0.000000
protests           0.000000
stategic           0.000000
riots              0.000000
fatalites          0.000000
future             1.000000
```

As a matter of fact, 90 percent of the 2 million or so network inputs look like this sparse example. At first I thought `np.inf` was a good stand in for `average_distance`, `average_time_diff` and `last_event`.

However, now that I have prepared my data, I am having a hard time scaling it before feed-forward (using `sklearn` scalers, for example).

Are there any established ways of dealing with this sort of thing? Or should I just choose to use some very large value instead of `np.inf`?

Dropping these samples is not an option as that would cause sample bias in my learning.

Comment: What kind of sample bias would introducing arbitrary values create?

Comment: @PaulH, Hmm, I'm not sure that it would introduce any bias if the arbitrary value was the same across samples. That's an option I was thinking of, especially for the average distance value.

Comment: Arbitrary value will not tell an algo "Look, this is a special value in a consistent way". You can impute with a big number (999....), mean and meadian could do. But a better option would be to find why you're getting inf and if it could be avoided

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov, It's because there were no nearest neighbors that met certain criteria, therefore I labeled average distance and time between neighbors as infinity. It was entirely my choice. I've since changed it to be a large number and my network seems to be training well.